# How to use Docker Remote API to assign a static IP address to a container

Tags: docker

When I use Docker Remote API to create a container, I don't know how to assign a IP address because I don't find the parameter about it.So how can I use Docker Remote API to create a container with a static IP address?

My Docker Server&Client version is 1.10.3, and API version is 1.22

Comment: The website tell me that I need 15 reputation to vote. When I earn enough reputation, I will vote u at once. Thx for your  answer again!! : )

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API will let you set a V4 and/or V6 static IP

`POST /networks/(id)/connect`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/#v1-22-api-changes